# Is it possible to access a server's IIS on home network from an android device 4G network via VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, iis, browsing

I have a Windows computer residing in my home network. The computer acts as a webserver for my own personal devices (laptop/android/iOS). The reason for this is that I deploy my home automation website to the webserver (IIS). All of this works very well when all devices are connected to my home network and I can browse the home automation website.

[image: Home network]

This works well!

Now I want to access my home network from my android even when I'm not physically at home (not on home network).

The problem is that my home server does not have a public IP address.

If I buy a VPN-service (like [purevpn](https://www.purevpn.com/why-purevpn.php)) and install their vpn client on all my devices, I believe that the devices will be on the same VPN network? Will the vpn clients provide my devices with an internal "VPN IP" (not sure if such exists?) so that I can browse the home automation website on my home server from my android device, even if I'm not at home?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 90% right.

Rather than buying access to somebody elses VPN server, you want to run your own. Setup OpenVPN or similar on the IIS host, setup some kind of DynDNS and forward whatever port you choose. Run a client on the phone. Then you will have full access as if you were sitting on your couch.

Comment: Seems to be a great idea! I'll check it up and be back before I mark this as an answer!

Comment: I believe this is a correct answer. Tried to  configure OpenVPN on my host accordinng to lots of  different tutotorials out there without sucess. But lousy tutorials are a different questions!